# Keep python script running and continue bash script? (Mac OSX)

Tags: python, bash, ssh

What I'm trying to do is run a python script that forwards ports so I can SSH into my phone using USB. The problem is if I set up a command like this:

```
# This is how I set up the port forwarding
python /path/to/tcprelay.py -t 22:2222

# Time to SSH
shh -l root -p 2222 127.0.0.1
```

the python script doesn't end (because it keeps forwarding, which I need it to do), so the ssh command never runs. I tried

```
xterm -e python /path/to/tcprelay.py -t 22:2222
```

but then it opens up XQuartz, runs the script there, but the ssh command still won't run until I end the python script in XQuarts.

How would I run the python script and continue my bash script simultaneously?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `&` to the end of your command to tell your shell to execute it ["in the background"](http://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/Putting_jobs_in_background):

```
python /path/to/tcprelay.py -t 22:2222 &
```

At least in `bash` (possibly in other shells?), you can bring a job back into the foreground with `fg`, and get a list of background jobs with `jobs`.